# Fourier analysis: decreases faster than polynomials

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f$ be a real-valued, bounded and continuous function with its derivative $f'$ bounded. Set
$$
f_n(x)=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{n}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)e^{-\frac{n|y-x|^2}{2}}dy.
$$
Then $f_n\to f$ as $n\to\infty$, and $f_n(x)$ decreases faster than $|x|^m$ for any power $m$ as $|x|\to\infty$. I want to prove that $f_n$ can be expressed by
$$
f_n(x)=\int e^{izx}\theta(z)dz,
$$
where $i=\sqrt{-1}$ and $\theta(z)$ satisfies that $\int (1+|z|^2)|\theta(z)|dz<\infty$. How do I prove this? Or, is there any known result that can justify this? Thanks.

PS: By the change of variable, we see that
\begin{align*}
f_n(x)&=e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{n}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\frac{u}{\sqrt{n}}+x)e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}du\\
&=e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{n}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(f(x)+\frac{f'(c)u}{\sqrt{n}}\right)e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}du,\;c\in(x,\frac{u}{\sqrt{n}}+x)\\
&=e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{n}}\left(f(x)+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right).
\end{align*}